# Deploying an upstart project on a systemd machine with Capistrano

Tags: systemd, upstart, capistrano

I am trying to configure a deployment for a Ubuntu 14.0.4 app on a RHEL 7 machine and the upstart-systemd difference is causing a lot of issues (foreman scripts ...).

Does anyone have experience on that end? Modifying the standard capistrano deployment (not using any custom tasks) to instead use systemd scripts?

I know capistrano-foreman-systemd is available, but I can't find too much info for this specific case. Only more questions.

Capfile example:

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require "capistrano/setup"

# Includes default deployment tasks
require "capistrano/deploy"

# Includes tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
require "capistrano/rails"

# Foundation
require "capistrano/foundation"

Dir.glob("lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake").each { |r| import r }
```

Nothing fancy in the tasks folder. I imagine I would need to override the standard foreman, puma tasks and run systemd exports instead.